# What are the device limitations for installing Linux-based Android alternatives?

Tags: linux, android, mobile, alternatives, smartphone

I have a new Samsung Galaxy A40 and would like to use a Linux-based alternative to Android. Reasons: Privacy/security, hackability, moving away from Google.

1.) Can I install an alternative OS even though my device is not explicitly supported? If not, what are the limiting factors? Does each device require a specific set of drivers (e.g. graphics, audio, peripherals)?

2.) Are there any good OS options? Is anyone using Ubuntu Touch? The OS should be safe, stable and user-friendly. Also, using standard device functions and installing/sideloading APKs of standard apps (e.g. WhatsApp/Telegram/KakaoTalk) should be straightforward with no extensive workarounds required.

PS.: I have no experience as a mobile developer.

Answer (score 1):

You should see [postmarketOS](https://postmarketos.org/). It can help with installing Alpine linux on the smartphones and adding different drivers to the distro(for working GSM, camera ...)